# ng1 - controller behave weird, dealing with JSON data handling : mark a pin on map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, controller

I am very new to AngularJS I spent a day n half to solve this, somehow it works now as I intended (only half I guess). **but I want this work completely.**

---

---

**There will be LONG question here. YOU CAN JUST GO DOWN and SEE FULL CODE & BIG PROBLEM, then PLEASE GIVE A HINT**

---

> **Legend:**
>
> **Yellow box statement : phase I could make something done.**
>
> **Bold statement : phase I failed and question**
>
> **Green statement : code**

Trying to mark a pin on the map (not google).

> I made a map with third-party map directive and tried to get and
>   return  lat,lng from my JSON file.
>
> I could get JSON data via factory and link this with
>   controller. I can see my data array on console.

```
function PointController(Points){
        var vm = this;
        vm.point = [];
        activate();
        function activate(){
          return all();
        }
        // half of success below code
        function all(){
          return Points.all()
            .then(function(response){
              vm.point = response;
              };
```

**then I tried to pull out only lat and lng value from inside of function to fetch the data. but no luck. I guess it didn't work because JSON is asynchronous?**

```
//let's say below vm.test2 is second. below code is outside of function to get JSON data
    vm.lat = vm.point[1].latitude <-------failed. 
    vm.lng = vm.point.data[1].longitude <--------- failed.
    vm.test2 = {
      position : {
        latitude : vm.lng,
        longitude : vm.lat
      },
      label : vm.address
    };
    }
```

> Again, I tried this action inside function to get data in controller. and I could get lat,lng set.

```
        .then(function(response){
          vm.point = response;
          vm.lat = response.data[1].latitude;
          vm.lng = response.data[1].longitude;
          vm.address = response.data[1].jibunaddress;
// let's say below vm.test2 is first vm.test2
          vm.test2 = {
            position : {
              latitude : vm.lng,
              longitude : vm.lat
            },
            label : vm.address
          };
```

**Now, I can use my lat, lng data. however I still couldn't use this data outside of this function. vm.test2 in html controller can't get this lat,lng data.**

to solve this, I tried tons of ways in google, and changed code **a lot**

> **somehow it works now, I can mark a pin with my JSON lat,lng through the code inside the function.**

```
   function all(){
      return Points.all()
        .then(function(response){
          vm.point = response;
          vm.lat = response.data[1].latitude;
          vm.lng = response.data[1].longitude;
          vm.address = response.data[1].jibunaddress;
// let's say below vm.test2 is first vm.test2
          vm.test2 = {
            position : {
              latitude : vm.lng,
              longitude : vm.lat
            },
            label : vm.address
          };
```

---

---

---

> **BIG PROBLEM :    When I load my site at first, I can see my pin located in second vm.test2's lat,lng.  but in a moment, it moves to
>   where first vm.test2's lat,lng**
>
> **If I delete below code(second vm.test2 outside of function) in my js, I can't get a pin on a map.**
>
> **I guess my marker function depends on both of vm.test2, WHAT IS THE PROBLEM? AND How can I solve this?**

```
  vm.test2 = {       <---------**this is second vm.test2**
    position : {
      latitude : vm.lng,
      longitude : vm.lat
    },
    label : vm.address
  };
```

Here is my JSON, Factory, Controller, HTML file..

```
   [   {"id":1,"creator":{"id":1,"email":"tsby@gmail.com","username":"Jae",
        "created_at":"2016-07-10T18:22:26.767233Z",
        "updated_at":"2016-07-10T18:22:26.767233Z",
        "first_name":"",
        "last_name":"",
        "tagline":""},
        "jibunaddress":"gurogu sindorim dong 400-1",
        "longitude":333.0,"latitude":333.0,
        "created_at":"2016-07-10T18:26:54.797563Z",
        "updated_at":"2016-07-10T18:26:54.798563Z"},
        {"id":2,"creator":{"id":1,"email":"tsby@gmail.com",
        "username":"Jae","created_at":"2016-07-10T18:22:26.767233Z",
        "updated_at":"2016-07-10T18:22:26.767233Z",
        "first_name":"","last_name":"","tagline":""},
        "jibunaddress":" test address yes yes baby",
        "longitude":37.3,"latitude":127.01,
        "created_at":"2016-07-11T09:34:27.275491Z",
        "updated_at":"2016-07-11T09:34:27.275491Z"}                            ]
```

Factory

```
angular
    .module('angularDaumMap')
    .factory('Points',Points);

  Points.$inject = ['$http'];

  /**
  * @namespace Points
  * @return {factory}
  */
  function Points($http){
    return {
      all : all
    };
    function all(){
      return $http.get('/api/v1/locations/');
    }
  }
```

Controller

```
angular
  .module('angularDaumMap')
  .controller('PointController',PointController);

  PointController.$inject = ['Points','$filter'];

  function PointController(Points,$filter){
    var vm = this;
    vm.point = [];
    activate();
    function activate(){
      return all();
    }
    // half of success below code
    function all(){
      return Points.all()
        .then(function(response){
          vm.point = response;
          vm.lat = response.data[1].latitude;
          vm.lng = response.data[1].longitude;
          vm.address = response.data[1].jibunaddress;

 **let's say below vm.test2 is first vm.test2**

          vm.test2 = {
            position : {
              latitude : vm.lat,
              longitude : vm.lng
            },
            label : vm.address
          };
          });
        }

**let's say below vm.test2 is second.**

vm.test2 = {
  position : {
    latitude : vm.lat,
    longitude : vm.lng
  },
  label : vm.address
};
}
```

and html file.

```
<div  ng-controller="MapController">
<daum-map center="map.center" draggable="map.draggable" level="map.level" map-type-id="map.mapTypeId" events="events">
  <daum-marker position="orig.position">
  </daum-marker>

<div ng-controller="PointController as vm">
  <daum-marker position="vm.test2.position">
  </daum-marker>
  </div>
</div>
</daum-map>
```

Comment: Functions that are arguments of   `.then` methods are always invoked after all the code in the parent functions. The code you call "the second vm.test2" is always executed first. What you call "the first vm.test2" is always executed later. That's the way the `$q` service works.

Comment: OK, Thanks, I got it the code flow. So any comment to make it available to use only one?(please..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Update: I delete my second vm.test2 in my code, and somehow it works now. Below Controller is complete code that works well.**

```
angular
  .module('angularDaumMap')
  .controller('PointController',PointController);

  PointController.$inject = ['Points'];

  function PointController(Points){
    var vm = this;
    vm.point = [];
    activate();
    function activate(){
      return all();
    }
    // below code is success 
    function all(){
      return Points.all()
        .then(function(response){
          vm.point = response.data;
          vm.lat = response.data[1].latitude;
          vm.lng = response.data[1].longitude;
          vm.address = response.data[1].jibunaddress;
// let's say below vm.test2 is first vm.test2
          vm.test2 = [];
          for (i = 7; i < vm.point.length; i++){
              var lng = response.data[i].latitude;
              var lat = response.data[i].longitude;
              vm.test2.push({
                  position : {
                      latitude : lat,
                      longitude : lng
                  }

              });
              console.log(vm.test2);
          }
          return vm.test2;
        });
       }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html seems wrong, you are closing the wrapping div before closing the daum-map tap

Comment: Yes I fixed the code, but that wasn't killing issue.
any idea that I can pin a marker on map with only one vm.test2 in my controller?